# Your Android SK missing,out of date,or is missing templates. You can configure SDK via "Configure - Project Defaults - Project Structure - SDKs

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo instalado Android studio y el JDK de Java instalado en Linux(Ubuntu) y me sale este mensaje

> "Your Android SK missing,out of date,or is missing templates. You can
>   configure SDK via  "Configure - Project Defaults - Project Structure -
>   SDKs "

¿alguien conoce la direccion por default de SDK de android en ubuntu? la verdad no la encuentro por ningún lugar o ¿cual podría ser la solución ?

Disculpen soy Novato en esto de android no hace mucho que estoy en este mundo ( Hace 2 semanas que estoy con android vengo de Java)

Answer (score 2):

Para saber esto necesitas tener instalado el SDK Tools, normalmente se instala (por lo menos en Windows) cuando instalar el Android Studio, desde ahí puedes seleccionar y descargar el SDK de android que necesites.

Answer (score 1):

**Probablemente no tienes instalado el Android SDK**, puedes ver un tutorial completo de como realizar la instalación completa de Android Studio y su SDK aquí:

https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?pkg=tools

para instalar únicamente el Android SDK:

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Si aseguras tener instalado el Android SDK entonces probablemente el path definido en el proyecto es incorrecto.

Da click boton derecho en tu proyecto (o F4) y abre `Open module settings`, ahí puedes configurar la ruta donde tengas tu Android SDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]